# Interrupt vector address - physical vs logical

Tags: interrupt, memory-address, interrupt-handling

If we use vectored interrupts in CPU that supports virtual address and has implemented Memory Management Unit, what type of address are the final interrupt vector stored in RAM? Physical or logical? If physical, how the MMU knows his logical address?

Sorry for my English.